# MySQL SP aborts suddenly when called from Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying to call a MySQL (Maria) stored procedure from a Google Apps Script.

If I execute the SP directly in MySQL, it runs for about 20-30 seconds and inserts 36 new rows in an existing table. It runs without errors, it never fails and it always finishes.

When I call the same SP from Google Apps Script,, it stops about halfway through execution. No error messages, and always in the exact same place.

The script I use to call it looks like this:

```
function execCalc() {

var query = "{ call calcder() }";
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(xxxxxxxxxx);

try {
  var stmt = conn.prepareCall(query); 
  stmt.executeQuery();
} catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
}

stmt.close();
conn.close();
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why this would be happening?

Comment: How do you know it stops halfway? If no error is thrown, the script should reach `stmt.close()` right? It's not getting there?

Comment: I don't use Google Apps Script, but is it possible that there is some kind of maximum execution time that aborts this?

Comment: Because I know what the procedure is meant to do. When I run it directly in MySQL it inserts 36 rows. When I run it from the script it only inserts 15 rows, and it doesn't perform some tasks at the end of it.

Comment: @Mark - Yes, I suppose that is possible, but first of all I would have thought that once an SP had been started in the database, then it would finish no matter what, and second it is not really not that long, 20 seconds or so seems like a very low upper limit.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I notice your use of `executeQuery` without processing the result set. Maybe you need to process all rows, or use `executeUpdate`. For example, I use Firebird, which has 'selectable procedures', and that type of procedure only makes progress if rows are fetched. This fetching happens in batches. So if you fetch the first 20 rows, then any subsequent rows that the stored procedure could generate will not actually happen: you need to iterate over the entire result set to ensure the stored procedure does all its work. I'm not sure if something similar happens in MariaDB.

Comment: I think that is a really good guess :) - the problem seems also to be related to the new Google Apps Script runtime called v8. If I downgrade to the previous version, and then also change from executeQuery to executeUpdate, that fixes the problem.

Comment: Have you check view executions to see if there is any errors in there.

Comment: There is a difference in that you're not getting an error, but I think your problem is most likely related to this issue: [Problems with V8 runtime and JDBC](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149413841), what do you think?